# Mean day with hourly data from a week

Tags: matlab, matrix, average, mean, days

I have a matrix with 24*7 rows(hourly data from the column week) and 52 columns(weeks in a year).

I want to calculate the average day (with 24h) from each week (resulting with a 24-by-52 matrix). Normaly I would `reshape` the vector from each week so that I could have 24 rows and 7 columns and then I could make the average from each hour, resulting in a average day from that week.

However, the year has 52 weeks, so this `reshape` is not realistic. 
Does anyone knows how to calculate the mean of each hour of a day in order to create one mean day using without reshaping the initial column for each week?

Comment: Do I get this correctly, you have a matrix, where each column represents the hour-values in one week (24*7) and now you want that average (resulting in a 1x52 vector?)? Or just the average for each day resulting in a 7x52 matrix?

Comment: or do you want just the overall day average 7x1 array?

Comment: No. I have a matrix with 24*7 rows and 52 columns. Each column represents a week. I want a final matrix with 24 rows and 52 columns, so that i can represent each week for its average day.

Comment: Are the values ordered like this: day1hour1;day1hour2;day1hour3 etc. or like this day1hour1;day2hour1;day3hour1 etc.?

Comment: day1hour1;day1hour2;day1hour3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand why not use `reshape`?

```
reshaped = reshape( allData, [24 7 52] );
avg = mean( reshaped, 2 ); %// average over the seven days
```

You might want to [`squeeze`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/squeeze.html) the result at the end...

Comment: Was writing the same answer, I think this is the way to go (up you go)

Comment: With the reshape I wouldn´t be sure about the values because I'm not very good at matlab and once that reshape would be in 3D I wouldn´t to be able to confirm what I was doing. Anyway, thank you very much for your help. I've done this with a for loop, finally I got it. Thank you anyway!

Comment: @PingP if you want to avoid reshaping into 3D you can `reshape` to 7x(24*52), then `mean` the columns, then `reshape` back.

Comment: @PingP you can try the `reshape` thing as an exercise, after you implemented the `for` loop and then you can compare the two results to verify that you indeed got it right. this exercise should improve your understanding and confidence using Matlab.

Answer (score 0):

If you really really really don't want to use `reshape`, you can use [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html).
First construct the indices relating the inputs in the 24*7-by-52 input to the 24-by-52  output:

```
rows = repmat( 1:24, [1 7*52] );
cols = repmat( 1:52, [7*24 1] );
avg = accumarray( [rows(:) cols(:)], allData(:), [24 52], @mean );
```